# Performing actions on duplications of type struct

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to understand how to work with structs in C, and I stumbled across Lists. I found the following definition of a list in C:

```
typedef struct ListNode∗ List;

struct ListNode {
   int item;
   List next;
};
```

Let us say I have a function that can create a new List and it produced a List li with item = 1 and next = someList.

Then I create copy li into a new variable and perform some action on it:

```
List li1 = li;
li1->item = 2;
```

Now does this change also affect li itself? Meaning `li->item` now also is 2?

I guess what I am really asking is if I actually duplicated the struct type or just created another reference to it. Could someone clarify this for me?

Comment: A debugger would be a perfect tool to clarify this very easily. Look at the addresses where your pointers point, look at the content of that memory.

Comment: Never ever typedef a pointer!

Comment: ..but if you do anyway, ensure it's appropriately named, eg 'pNode', so it's clear it's a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `li` is pointing to a valid `ListNode` object, then

```
List li1 = li;
```

creates a copy of *the pointer*. After the above definition and initialization, you have two pointers (`li` and `li1`) both pointing to the very same object.

If you want a *deep* copy then you need to implement it explicitly, which for a list means copying every node in the list.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess what I'm really asking is if I actually duplicated the struct type or just created another reference to it. Could someone clarify this for me?

Your type `List` is not a structure type but only a pointer to a structure.
BTW: It is considered bad practice to hide pointers within typedefs.

When you copy `li` you only copy the pointer to your list and this means that you also alter the data where `li` is pointing to.